# Handling signed_request. Should I check referrer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Should I be checking referrer host when handling `signed_request` supposedly sent by Facebook? As far as I can see, this would only be useful if `secret key` is compromised.

It looks like all `signed_requests` are sent from `86.29.235.94`. But it could be regional thing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, referer is not predictable. There are no defined rules around that and it may be subject to change. Also, some user agents don't even send one.

Unfortunately the signed_request scheme does not allow for data confidentiality (via encryption) or source integrity, but you do get data integrity so you can at least be assured that a valid signed_request was generated by Facebook at some point. For verifying that, you simply need to check the signature. This doesn't guarantee you're not falling victim to a replay attack, but I don't think anyone has ever solved that problem.

You may be able to do something with the "issued_at" property as a nonce but I haven't tested enough to know whether it works correctly across all requests.

Answer (score 1):

If your app secret is compromised, receiving an invalid signed_request is probably the least of your worries

The attacker would have to also have to get hold of a valid access token for one of your app's users in order for injecting a signed_request to grant them access to your app, wouldn't they?

Comment: You are right. `access_token` is another show stopper. Well then, there isn't much need to worry about referring host.